# PHP get data form XML using PHPSimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to get data from an xml file and am having trouble as the table has a bit more levels than the examples I can find.

I want to be able to iterate through each instance of `<Event>` as `<Information>` and `<Events>` only open and close the data. The `<Event>` repeats based on the number of events logged.

A sample of the table structure is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Information>
    <Events>
        <Event>
            <Time>3141.29</Time>
            <PrimaryObject ID="487">
                <Name>Player1</Name>
                <Country>us</Country>
            </PrimaryObject>
            <Action>Move</Action>
            <SecondaryObject ID="814">
                <Name>Dog</Name>
                <Parent>487</Parent>
            </SecondaryObject>
        </Event>
    </Events>
</Information>
```

The PHP code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("data.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
foreach($xml->Event as $events) {
    $id = $events->PrimaryObject->attributes();
    $name = $events->PrimaryObject->Name;
    ...
    echo $id['ID'].' '. $name;
    echo "<br>";
  }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the *Events*

```
$xml->Events->Event as $events
```

For example

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("data.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

foreach($xml->Events->Event as $events) {
    $id = $events->PrimaryObject->attributes();
    $name = $events->PrimaryObject->Name;
    echo $id['ID'].' '. $name;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Output

```
487 Player1
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/1CSaM)

Comment: As an extra tip, you don't actually need the `->attributes()` here, you can just do `$id = $events->PrimaryObject['ID']`, or `$id = (string)$events->PrimaryObject['ID']` if you're passing it somewhere else and want just the value and not the object representing the attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what data exactly you are looking for, but here's everything, using xpath, and you can pick and choose:

```
$events = $xml->xpath('.//Event');
foreach($events as $event) {        
    $dat = $event->xpath('./PrimaryObject')[0];
    $time= $event->xpath('./Time');    
    $id = $dat->xpath('./@ID');
    $name = $dat->xpath('./Name');
    $country = $dat->xpath('./Country');
    
    $dat2 = $event->xpath('./SecondaryObject')[0];
    $action= $event->xpath('./Action');    
    $id2 = $dat2->xpath('./@ID');
    $name2 = $dat2->xpath('./Name');
    $parent = $dat2->xpath('./Parent');    
            
    echo 'Time: ' . $time[0];
    echo "<br>"; 
    echo 'Action: ' . $action[0];
    echo "<br>";    
    echo "<br>"; 
    echo 'Primary Object Data:';
    echo "<br>";    
    echo 'ID: ' . $id[0];
    echo "<br>";
    echo 'Name: ' . $name[0];
    echo "<br>";
    echo 'Country: ' . $country[0];
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";   
    echo "<br>";
    echo 'Secondary Object Data:';
    echo "<br>";    
    echo 'ID: ' . $id2[0];
    echo "<br>";
    echo 'Name: ' . $name2[0];
    echo "<br>";
    echo 'Parent: ' . $parent[0];
    echo "<br>";         
  }
```

Output:

```
Time: 3141.29
Action: Move

Primary Object Data:
ID: 487
Name: Player1
Country: us


Secondary Object Data:
ID: 814
Name: Dog
Parent: 487
```